# How to Add image icon next to Click VIew Text?

Tags: flutter

Wanted to add a image icon next to Click View Text

```
 child: Row(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: [
          Column( // Wrap the text and detail sentence in a Column
            children: [
              Text(
                "Click View",
                style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 20, color: Color.fromRGBO(255, 201, 102, 100)),
              ),
              Padding(padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 30)),
              Text(
                "Additional detail sentence", // Add your detail sentence here
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14, color: Colors.grey), // Customize the style as needed
              ),
            ],
          ),
         
        ],
      ),
```

[image]

Add image icon next to Text

Answer (score 1):

Try to wrap your first Text("Click View") widget within a Row() then add an Icon widget as the second children of the Row.

```
Row(
 children [
   Text( 
     "Click View",
      style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 20, 
         color: Color.fromRGBO(255, 201, 102, 100)),
          ),
   Icon()// add your icon widget here
  ]
)
```

Then customize it as you preferred.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
Row( mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min, children: [ Icon( Icons.view_module, // Replace with the desired icon color: Color.fromRGBO(255, 201, 102, 100), // Customize the icon color size: 20, // Customize the icon size ), SizedBox(width: 8), // Add some space between the icon and text Column( crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start, children: [ Text( "Click View", style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 20, color: Color.fromRGBO(255, 201, 102, 100)), ), Padding(padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8)), // Adjust the padding as needed Text( "Additional detail sentence", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14, color: Colors.grey), ), ], ), ], )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This one
this may work

```
 Column(
                  // Wrap the text and detail sentence in a Column
                  children: [
                    Row(
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          "Click View",
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              fontSize: 20,
                              color: Color.fromRGBO(255, 201, 102, 100)),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          width: 5,
                        ),
                        Icon(Icons.view_carousel_outlined)
                      ],
                    ),
                    Padding(padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 30)),
                    Text(
                      "Additional detail sentence", // Add your detail sentence here
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 14,
                          color: Colors.grey), // Customize the style as needed
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).